# PHP Not 'Syncing' with MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a mySQL DB that contains user information. Information is added to the DB using a user registration system, which is working properly. Here's an example user (PHPmyadmin): [image]

Issue is that I have a PHP based 'my account' page that retrieves info about the user's account. This informaiton doesn't seem to be in sync with the MySQL when I update user information from PHPMyAdmin or even when I add new data about a user (for example, my PHP won't detect the newly-added 'RealName' field although it recognizes the 'EmailAddress' field which has been there for a while.

PHP/HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <img src="assets/user.jpg" style="border-radius:150px;height:150px;width:150px;float:left;"><br>
        <h2 class="desc" style="font-style: normal;padding:0px;margin:0px;float:left;">&nbsp <?=$_SESSION['RealName']?></h2><br><br>
        <h4 class="desc" style="font-style: normal;padding:0px;margin:0px;float:left;"><i>&nbsp &nbsp @<?=$_SESSION['Username']?></i></h4><br><br>
        <hr>
        <a href=""><p class="desc" style="font-style: normal;float:left;">&nbsp &nbsp Change Profile Image...</h2></a> <a href=""><p class="desc" style="font-style: normal;float:left;">&nbsp &nbsp Change Your Name...</h2></a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer-alt"><br><br>
        <h4>Account Info &nbsp</h4>
        <p class="desc" style="font-style: normal;float:left;"><b>E-Mail Address: </b><?=$_SESSION['EmailAddress']?> &nbsp</p> <code style="float:left;">Private</code><br><br>
        <p class="desc" style="font-style: normal;float:left;"><b>Password: </b> ●●●●●●●●●● &nbsp</p> <code style="float:left;">Private</code><br>
        <h4>Bio &nbsp</h4>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="40"><?=$_SESSION['Bio']?></textarea>
        <h4>More &nbsp</h4>
        <a href="../account/die.php"><button class="btn btn-default">Log Out</button></a><a href="../account/die.php"><button class="btn btn-default">Sign Up for Contributor Rewards</button></a>
</div>
```

How it appears on the webpage:
[image]
Notice that some of the info appears and other info doesn't. This isn't an issue with my HTML as if I replace the PHP with a static value, it displays fine.

This is the code I use to start the session:

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbhost = "PRIVATE"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ
$dbname = "PRIVATE"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project
$dbuser = "PRIVATE"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your database
$dbpass = "PRIVATE"; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

Log off code:

```
<?php include "base.php"; $_SESSION = array(); session_destroy(); ?>
```

Comment: You're pulling the data out of the session. Does your code update the session values on every pageview?

Comment: It looks like the page is displaying information from the session, not directly from the database. Could you post the code that gets it from the database to the session?

Comment: No, it does not. However, I have tried logging out and logging back in - shouldn't that kill the session?

Comment: if your log off function works properly, maybe. Try to close the browser completely and/or using incognito mode before logging in again

Comment: did you call `session_start()` before reading from $_SESSION? done `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see if you have what you think you have?

Comment: logging off does NOT kill session.  session should be explicitely destroyed `session_destroy()`

Comment: @tony I included the code I call each logoff in the question. It uses session_destroy. Session.start(); is called in base.php which is included on each webpage that handles accounts.

Comment: Note that `mysql` is not supported anymore. Try using `mysqli` or `pdo` instead.

Comment: Also, don't use MD5 hashes... salt hashes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload your `$_SESSION` values... This can be achieved by creating a page `logout.php` and having the functions `session_start(); session_destroy();` in it. Your login page will need to be updated to have the correct session data as well.

Comment: I already do that. my logout.php includes those lines as I stated in the question. Session_start() is called on page login.

Comment: On page login, are you setting DB values to the `$_SESSION`? That's the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I figured it out. I'm setting some of the values, but not others.

Comment: No problem. You should also look at tony gil's answer. I agree with him regarding the workflow.

Answer (score 3):

i disagree with your workflow and would not use this method.  in everything user related, i trust only latest data from DB (or authenticating authority, in case of OAuth or OpenId, for example), never stored session data.

i would query the DB every time i needed critical info like userdata.  a user may change his/her name in the middle of a session and this should be reflected realtime by your system.

i would also refrain from `OR DIE`.  please consider using `try...catch` and treating the error.

```
try {
  include ('ConnectionData.php'); // user, pass, db, localhost
  $sqlGetId = "SELECT etcetcetc";
  $sqlResultGetId = mysql_query($sqlGetId);
  $rowGetId = mysql_fetch_array($sqlResultGetId);
  if ( $rowGetId[0] > 0 ) {
    // consume data
```